# Detect When Div scrolls out of view

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, detect

I have a div box with all the page content within it called `.body-Container`

and there is a div box that is placed on top of the `.body-Container` which is acting like a cover called `.coverImg`.

What I am trying to achieve is having the `.body-Container` positioned fixed until the `.coverImg` scrolls out of view, then changes position from fixed to relative. To allow the user to continue on viewing the content.

Then reverse, when scrolled to the top of the web page `.body-Container` becomes fixed and the `.coverImg` comes back into view.

I have given the `.coverImg` a `magin-bottom:100vh` which allows the div to scroll out of view.

I am having difficulty detecting when the bottom of the div hits the top of the window. To change the positioning.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ra48qumb/4/) to give a better understanding of what I am trying to do.

HTML:

```
<div class="coverImg" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.creativelive.com/fit/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.creativelive.com%2Fagc%2Fcourses%2F5158-1.jpg/640);">
</div>

<div class="body-Container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class='section'>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
    </div>
    <div class='section'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.body-Container {
  position: relative;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 99vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.coverImg {
  width: 90%;
  height: 150vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  height: 2500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: skyblue;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something along the lines of this may help. Each time the user scrolls, you're checking the position of the bottom of the div - if it's less than 0 (top of the window) you add the class `outOfView` (where you can add your position styling), if not, you remove the class:

```
    jQuery(window).on('scroll', function () {
        var top = jQuery(window).scrollTop(),
            divBottom = jQuery('.coverImg').offset().top + jQuery('.coverImg').outerHeight();
        if (divBottom > top) {
            jQuery('.coverImg').removeClass('outOfView');
        } else {
            jQuery('.coverImg').addClass('outOfView');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I had the logic in my head correct but was really finding it difficult to target the bottom of the div box. I just had to change `jQuery('.coverImg').removeClass('outOfView');` to `jQuery('.body-Container').removeClass('outOfView');` and it works a treat. Thanks again :)
Originally I was going to move the `.coverImg` using the translateY property, on scroll but I was out of my league for that haha.